# jQuery Mobile 1.4+ - preloading pages / precalculating offsets

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to perform some operations (calculating element offsets) on a dynamically created JQM page when my app first runs. At the moment the page is built too slowly and the code returns an offset of 0 for every element. It seems that caching it might be the answer (it's a multipage JQM app with a single HTML file). Older answers to this problem on SO suggested using `$.mobile.loadPage` but as of 1.4 this is deprecated. The jQuery API documentation isn't the clearest on this issue - it suggests using the `load` method of the pagecontainer widget

```
$( ".selector" ).pagecontainer( "load" );
```

and that

> The pagecontainer widget is designed to be a singleton instantiated by the framework on the **body** element.

I assumed this meant a pagecontainer is created automatically but if I try and run the snippet above I get an error saying I can't run pagecontainer methods before instantiating one. The [JQM pagecontainer reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) doesn't provide an example of how to instantiate one.

My questions are

1. Does preloading / caching actually render the page in the background? Will precalculating offsets even be possible?
2. Do I even need to use the pagecontainer `load` method to preload an internal page?
3. The docs seem to suggest that `load` is for loading external resources - is it relevant for internal "pages"?
4. Should I use something like `data-dom-cache="true"` instead? Or `data-prefetch`? These seem to be for external resources...

Would really appreciate some guidance on best practices here - the only other alternative is running a setTimeout on the offending page of the app while the code runs, but this is horrible.

Comment: when elements are hidden `display: none;` you cant retrieve their offset nor their dimensions.